# .htaccess "Options not allowed here"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I have this in my .htaccess:

Options +FollowSymLinks

And I get the following error in the apache error_log:

```
.htaccess: Options not allowed here
```

Here's the part from my httpd.conf file:

```
#htdocs symlinks here
<Directory /Users/you/code/my/folder>
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory />
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs">
    Options All 
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

So I'm setting Options All and AllowOverride All everywhere, but STILL I'm not allowed to set the option. Can anyone make sense of this?

Thanks,
MrB

Comment: What exactly is the URL you want to access and the local path where what you want to read is located? Don't use symlinks, change `DocumentRoot` appropriately to allow paths to be consistent.

Answer (score 28):

Note that this is a XAMPP-specific issue. XAMPP loads some additional configuration files located in `XAMPP/etc/extra/` that override httpd.conf. For me the offending file is `http-userdir.conf` which applies rules for ~user requests and contains the line `AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes` and changing that line to `AllowOverride All` did indeed solve my issue.

This only applies to files served from your /Sites/ directory on OS X. I don't know if the Windows version uses UserDir at all or even has a similar rule.

Comment: In addition, you can read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/es/mod/core.html#allowoverride too. That doc may help you to define specific values of AllowOverride ;)

Comment: This was helpful in conjunction with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22955171/970346).

Answer (score 6):

in my case I end up with change the line `AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo` to `AllowOverride All` in file httpd-vhosts.conf where this file is located in apache\conf\extra folder

Answer (score 4):

You have to allow overrides for "Options" within directory context. there's no need to:

```
vhost/directory config:
    AllowOverride All
```

But only to permit overrides for 'Options':

```
    AllowOverride {Existing options to override} +Options
```

Comment: did you mean `AllowOverride {Existing options to override} Options` (without the +)?

Comment: Yes. I couldn't find any reference to '+' on httpd manual page https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride referring to AllowOverride.

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is a global `AllowOverride` setting in your apache config which disallows this. Can you grep for AllowOverride in your httpd.conf?

Comment: $ cat httpd.conf | grep "AllowOverride"
    AllowOverride All
    AllowOverride All
    AllowOverride All
    AllowOverride All

Is it possible I'm editing the wrong httpd.conf? I'm editing the one in /Applications/XAMPP/etc/httpd.conf. How do I find out which config apache is using?

edit: using right httpd.conf, changed log file and it started logging into the other file..

Answer (score 2):

*I just installed the most recent version of XAMPP and thought to share how I solved the same problem.*

This is a XAMPP specific setting (with every new XAMPP install). The most recent up to date XAMPP as of today - **XAMPP 1.8.3** have a setting in /xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf that's causing your "Server Error" message.

And then you get the following error in your error log:

```
.htaccess: Options not allowed here
```

**Open /xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf and find:**

```
<Directory "/xampp/htdocs/xampp">
    <IfModule php5_module>
        <Files "status.php">
            php_admin_flag safe_mode off
        </Files>
    </IfModule>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>
```

**and change**

```
AllowOverride AuthConfig
```

**with**

```
AllowOverride All
```

No authentication or authorization will be required after the change UNLESS you specify it in your httpd.conf, extra confs or in .htaccess.

You may also want to read the Apache documentation for the option AllowOverride  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#allowoverride and choose more optimal and secure setting that will allow you to use your .htaccess without causing a server error.

Also keep in mind that you can find a better place to rewrite the rule above depending on the results that you'd like to achieve. In my case this is a satisfactory change.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Still valid till today.

Answer (score 2):

On Debian 9 i edited the file  /etc/apache2/mods-available/userdir.conf

Disabled this line
*AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes*

Added this line
  *Allowoverride All*

And it worked fine.

Many thanks to all who contributed

Answer (score 1):

instead of changing the global AllowOverride settings in your main httpd.conf file, if you have a httpd-vhosts.conf file you would want to put directory specific AllowOverride All directives in each host entry that you need it in, so you can keep a restrictive set on the rest of the server realm.

Answer (score 1):

Change `Options +FollowSymLinks` into `Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` in all instances of .htaccess file, the followsymlinks has been disabled on many server due to security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Does the server your domain is hosted on fulfills all requirements needed for Elgg? Especially, is mod_rewrite available?

Re-check all steps you had done.

If mod_rewrite is working... Do you have access to the configuration (http.conf) of Apache on your server? If yes, add the following lines (adjust the path):

AllowOverride All

Comment: Please consider adding additional background on your mention of "Elgg". I believe the author does not mention that framework anywhere in the original question.