# Cant see or access Laravel's public folder

Tags: php, laravel, fedora

On Fedora 20 I created a folder named `test` then installed Laravel via `composer create-project laravel/laravel` into it. It ran successfully and now I try to view it in FireFox in the following URL:

```
http://localhost/~username/test/laravel/public/
```

But it throws the following error:

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at root@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

If I go to the parent folder, I can see that everything is there except the `public` folder. However if I `ls` in the terminal I can see that the folder is right over there. There is no problem with other PHP scripts only with this project. I tried to play with folder permission but no success. Why can't I see the folder in the browser and why does it throws an Error 500 when I try to access it?

Comment: Isn't the laravel public folder at the root of localhost? I.e. localhost/file.txt will return public/file.txt

Comment: Try **My Solution** It will work **everywhere**.  check Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222509/laravel-not-detecting-files-from-public-folder/69517681#69517681

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Debugging

After I looked at `/var/log/httpd/error_log` I saw the following in the last line:

> [Tue May 20 09:37:21.874443 2014] [core:alert] [pid 2897] [client ::1:55498]
> `/home/username/public_html/test/laravel/public/.htaccess`:
> Options not allowed here, referer: `http://localhost/~username/test/`

### Make things work

So in my `public` folder I renamed the `.htaccess` file to `.htaccess2` and now it works. Of course now I need to write `index.php` after `public/` in the URL but at least it works. This also solved the invisible folder error, so if I go to the project root (the parent folder of `public`) in the browser it lists the `public` folder too.

### Try to fix it

[According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7802644/1494454) configurations in the `httpd.conf` file can be overwritten by other extra files. You should search these files for a line containing `AllowOverride` like `AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo` and replace it with `AllowOverride All`.

Comment: Had this issue this morning found that commenting out `RewriteEngine On` in the `public/.htaccess` file made it work.  Adding this line to htaccess made it work properly `Options +FollowSymLinks`