# Laravel not detecting files from public folder

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-4

hello people below is code of `.htaccess` inside public folder...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
</IfModule>
```

As though i have some images inside public folder...'not found error message is displayed'  ...anyways to fix this???

Comment: Are you sure you have mod_rewrite installed/enabled?  Try removing the first and last "IfModule" lines and see if you get any errors in the error log about mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

try changing it to this make sure this .htaccess is inside of your public folder.
inside app i have this other .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

and laravel works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It will work prefect in **Shared Server or other Server**.

For Fix this issue. i did some steps :

1. copy all files from **Public Folder** to **root Folder**.
2. change path in **index.php**  means replace it `'../'` to `"/"`.
3. update .**htaccess** file with this code.
4. I have also added a code for Hide **env** file. if you not add that code then anyone can see your **env** file.

   ```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]



    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.woff|\.woff2|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.svg|\.woff|\.woff2|\.ttf|\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.jpeg|\.docx|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(css|js|images|admin|userimage|ckedit_images|video|thumbnail|fonts|amenities-pic|img|propert|property_video|vendor|photos|files|doc|flags|1x1|4x3)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
   ```

   ```
   #hide a Specifuc Laravel .env File
   <Files .env>
   order allow,deny
   Deny from all
   </Files>
   ```