# Laravel 5.6 unable to import css file

Tags: css, laravel

I am trying to import css file but i just cant.

my css file is in "public/css/style.css"

i ve tried all possible combinations that i found on internet but nothing works

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{!! asset('css/style.css') !!}" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/style.css') }}" />
```

Laravel .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

but nothing just works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

i ma probably missing some configuration that i cant find out.
But i create virtual host with xampp and set `DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\final\public"` and this works.

Thanks for help guys.

Answer (score 2):

```
<link href="{!! asset('css/style.css') !!}" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Change That to This

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and it should work.

Comment: If this doesn't work, then make sure that you have properly set up your `.htaccess` (for apache) or your nginx config.

Comment: No it doesnt work and this is my laravel .htaccess. How  can i check if my .htacces is set properly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682748/assets-not-referencing-to-public-folder-laravel
this wont work too

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`<link href="./public/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

The ./ part is the current folder you are in.

Comment: it does not work.
this 
http://localhost:8000/public/css/style.css
and this
http://localhost:8000/css/style.css
shows up 404 error

Comment: How about mix.less('resources/assets/less/app.less', 'public/css');? Found it on https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#working-with-stylesheets.