# Laravel js file not found

Tags: javascript, laravel

I've my Laravel javascript file in public/js folder and it is referred like follows.

```
<script src="{{ asset('public/js/test.js') }}"></script>
```

But it is still not found 404.

Comment: put exact error which you are getting

Comment: You shouldn't refer to the public folder, the asset method does that for you. You should try `{{ asset('/js/test.js') }}`

Comment: remove `public` from address, the `asset` method reach to `public` folder, so the right way is : `<script src="{{ asset('js/test.js') }}"></script>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assets not referencing to public folder (Laravel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682748/assets-not-referencing-to-public-folder-laravel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to include `public` in the URL. This should work fine;

```
<script src="{{ asset('/js/test.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: This is surely a duplicate, no need to answer the question, rather mark it as such

Answer (score 0):

What is ASSET_URL value? You can check it in the web developer tool in chrome or firefox. You can configure the asset URL host by setting the ASSET_URL variable in your .env file. This can be useful if you host your assets on an external service like Amazon S3 (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-asset). For eg

```
// ASSET_URL=http://example.com/assets
asset('public/js/test.js') //http://example.com/assets/js/test.js
```

Usually your run your server document root as public folder. Hence, I am guessing that removing the public dir path will solve 404 file not found error i.e change to.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/test.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use  instead of   as public folder is added Automatically by asset

Comment: This answer is not clear enough. If you expand the answer you can flag this comment as being no longer needed.