# anchor tag download is not working on live laravel project

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am using this code to download the pdf files which are placed in main directory "public/download/ca/"
**CODE:**

```
      <a download="" class="download" target="_blank" href="{{ asset('download/ca/'.$doc->
              file_name) }}">
      </a>
```

It is working perfectly on my local server project also downloads the files but it is not working on my live server project, its showing "failed - Server Problem".

Comment: `$doc>file_name` -- you are missing a `-` there in `$doc->file_name`

Answer (score 0):

it is because asset appends your base url so maybe you need to fix this, you can look these here hope it helps:
[Assets not referencing to public folder (Laravel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682748/assets-not-referencing-to-public-folder-laravel)

https://laravel.io/forum/09-17-2014-problem-asset-not-point-to-public-folder

Comment: Brother it is working on my local machine its mean assets is referencing the public folder.

Comment: Thanks alot brother; The problem is file name was in capital letter and in db it was in lower case, but it was not occuring an issue in local server I dont know why.