# How to fix the path of external css in public folder in Express?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, ejs

Please help me to fix the path to load the external CSS files. I have tried many times, but it does not work out. Here is my category structure:

[image]

in the header.ejs, I include the path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />
```

I have tried many times, but it does not work

```
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '../../src/web/public/')));
// app.use('*/css',express.static('public/'));
// app.use("/static", express.static(path.resolve(__dirname + "/public/css")));
```

I keep getting this error:

Refused to apply style from 'localhost:3000/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: From where is `app.use` called/in which folder is the file where you call it?

Comment: @eol Hello eol. 'app.use' called from app.ts which is in the web folder. I just edited the image.

Comment: Try **My Solution** It will work **everywhere**.  check Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222509/laravel-not-detecting-files-from-public-folder/69517681#69517681

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the express.static is called within your app.js file (residing in the dist folder) and the public folder is included in the dist folder the following should work:

in your app.ts:

`app.use(express.static('public'))`

in your html/ejs:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
```

If you intend to keep the public-folder in the src-dir and not include it in your dist-package, you need to adjust the path in your app.ts file:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../src/web/public')));
```

Comment: I'm still getting this error: 
localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/css/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: What does you dist folder look like? I assume you're starting your node app from there? I can't see any public folder there..

Comment: Hi eol, dist folder just a place that typescript code execute and create js file. my public folder is on the src/web/public. Src folder is same level as dist folder. You meant I have to put public in dist folder? Sorry I am very new to NodeJS. Please help me solve this

Comment: Typescript is never executed directly, it always gets compiled to javascript which then is run. So yes, either package the public folder along the dist or you need to adjust the path in your app.ts. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hi eol. It's working now. Thank you so much. You are the best :D

Comment: Happy to help ;)