# htacces 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite the html extension shown in the URL bar like www.mywebsite.com/about.html to www.mywebsite.com/about using htacces.

This is the code I'm using but it doesn't seem to work. Could anyone tell me why this doesn't works? Any answers and/or explanations are much appreciated!

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home index.html
RewriteRule ^about about.html
RewriteRule ^services services.html
```

Comment: You will have to look in the Apache error logs (consult your host to find out where those logs are) to get details about the error. My guess is that you have rewrite loops because the pattern like `^services` would match both `/services` and `/services.html` then infinitely rewrite to `services.html`.  You probably just need to add the `[L]` flag to these and terminate them like `^services$`

Comment: What does the error log says ?

Comment: maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7097004/1992669

Comment: The error log says the following: _myurl/.htaccess: Option FollowSymLinks not allowed here_

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski you know what might cause the problem?

Comment: FollowSymLinks should be allowable in .htaccess (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options) but you may be trying to override the setting set in the server config.  If this is on a shared host server, contact their support team to ask if you can use FollowSymLinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it seems my hosting provider doesn't provide .htacces files. (Like what the F...). Thank you guys for thinking along. Cheers